# MySQL '%y' calculating wrong century

Tags: mysql, date

Im doing a string to date calculation for birthdays in one of my databases. The years are in a 2 digit format so obviously this is my code:

```
STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%m/%d/%y')
```

However this is calculating the incorrect century on a lot of records. IE: The birth year should be 1960 and instead is 2060.

Is this based on some sort of SQL standard for date formatting, or can I manually specify a century cutoff? Or other suggestions maybe?

Edit:
An example birthdate is '09/23/62'.

Returns formatted as '2062-09-23'

Comment: please provide more info. with actual data or example to get exact problem

Comment: I think that's standard. Years lower than "'70" are assumed to be 20XX.

Comment: Edited with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/two-digit-years.html):

- Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to 2000-2069.
- Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to 1970-1999.

There is no right or wrong: since you don't provide a century, MySQL has to guess. If the guessing is not what you want, you'll have to provide the century your self. Possible solutions depend on your DB schema.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your responses everyone. This is the workaround I ended up using:

```
IF(STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%m/%d/%y') > NOW(),SUBDATE(STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%m/%d/%y'), INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/year.html), this is the expected behaviour

> As a 1- or 2-digit string in the range '0' to '99'. Values in the
>   ranges '0' to '69' and '70' to '99' are converted to YEAR values in
>   the ranges 2000 to 2069 and 1970 to 1999.